# Why is it that we declare 2d arrays with 1 based indexing but we access the array with 0 based indexing in C language?

Tags: c, arrays

```
`int main()
{
int nums[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
printf("%d", nums[2][1]); 
return 0;
}`
```

Here, if I wanted to access the last element of the array, I would use [2][1] but to name the array, I would use 1 based indexing and use [3][2]. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Because 3 and 2 are the sizes in the other use they are indexes.

Comment: In `int nums[3][2]`, the `3` and `2` are not indices, they're lengths.  They are not 1-based, since there is no indexing being done.  They aren't 0-based either.  They are simply length values.

Comment: Thanks guys. I understand it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're confusing *length* with *indexes*. For an array of length *N* the indexes are *0* through *N-1*.

That is:

```
int x[3];
```

Means `x[0]`, `x[1]` and `x[2]` exist. There are 3 entries numbered 0 .. 2.

The length is only "1 based" because when we talk about a length 1 array we usually mean it can hold one entry, as in that's how humans tend to count. The index, however, is an *offset from the start*, as it's really an artifact of how C works internally:

```
x[n] // Array notation
*(x + n) // Pointer notation
```

Where when you say `x[0]` you're saying "apply a zero offset to the start of the array and read the value" which translates into human terms as "read the first element" even though the generated machine instructions look a lot more like the first explanation.

Other languages that implement 1-based arrays actually have to subtract that offset out in order to read the correct memory location. In other words *they're faking it*.

Comment: Oh! Right. Thank you.

Comment: @tadman I was on the verge of adding the `*(x + n)` example, but I'd rather upvote this. Even though you already are at 174k rep...

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Only got there one long-winded explanation at a time!

Answer (score 1):

When you "name" the array (the proper term is "declare/define"), the numbers represent the size, or more accurately the number of elements in the array.

When you access an element, you use the index of the element in the array, which is basically "how far, in number of elements, is it from the start of the array".

So first element has index 0.

Answer (score 0):

The number in the brackets of an array declaration is the number of elements, not the index of the last element. But this is an interesting deviation from the stated philosophy of how C declarations work.

Kernighan and Ritchie described how a declarator provided a sort of picture of an identifier being used, in *The C Programming Language*, 1978, page 90:

> The declaration of the pointer `px` is new.
>
> `int *px;`
>
> is intended as a mnemonic; it says the combination `*px` is an `int`, that is, if `px` occurs in the context `*px`, it is equivalent to a variable of the type `int`. In effect, the syntax of the declaration for a variable mimics the syntax of expressions in which the variable might appear. This reasoning is useful in all cases involving complicated declarations. For example,
>
> `double atof(), *dp;`
>
> says that in an expression `atof()` and `*dp` have values of type `double`.

Thus, we see that, in a declaration such as `int *p`, the `*p` gives us a “picture” of an expression that `p` will be used in. The actual type for the identifier is derived from the picture: Since `*p` is an `int`, then `p` is a pointer to an `int`.

If we were faithful to this model, then `int x[2]` would tell us that `x[2]` is an `int`, so `x` must be an array of `int` and it must have a member with index 2, so it must be an array of at least 3 `int`. Instead, it was decided the declarator would contain the number of elements instead of the maximum index.

This is largely an arbitrary decision—a compiler could be designed to work either way. I do not see that Kernighan and Ritchie discuss this choice, in either of the editions of *The C Programming Language*. They refer to the number as a “bound” on the array size, but it is not stated why they deviated from the “picture” scheme to use a number of elements instead of a sample index. (Oddly, I do not even see a statement that the number is the number of elements. I see examples that indicate it but no explicit statement.)